# Mysql Use of MAX in a subquery

Tags: mysql, max

Why can't I use that subquery which returns a group error ?

```
SELECT hs.dateFin, hs.codeAdherent, hs.codeArticle 
FROM hs 
WHERE hs.codeFamilleArticle IN ('CNI', 'COT', 'ABO', 'ABOW',
                                'CNIW', 'O&T', 'EPH', 'TAX') 
AND codeAdherent != 0 
AND MAX(hs.dateFin) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' 
                        AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY hs.codeAdherent
```

The same data exists for 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31 but I only want to get the ones that end in 2017.
Here under a sample of table which contains 140000 raws (not all columns are showed).

[image: Here]

codeAdherent A has data for 2018, 2017, 2016.

codeAdherent B has data for2018, 2017

codeAdherent C only for 2017.

If I do a select on 2017 I get all three codeAdherent, then the MAX BETWEEN will exclude A and B... But that's doesn't work

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with that `MAX(hs.dateFin)`?

Comment: data exists for  adherent each year. I want to know those who stopped previous year

Comment: Still not really clear. Please add sample data and the expected result. A few rows will go a long way.

Comment: Learn about `GROUP BY ` and aggregation.  `MAX()` in `WHERE` clause will definitely not work.

Comment: Read this to learn how to ask question.  Posting a broken query without telling us what you are trying to do will not help us help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I update my request with sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check if no record exists for 2018:

```
SELECT dateFin, codeAdherent, codeArticle
FROM hs AS t
WHERE codeFamilleArticle IN ('CNI', 'COT', 'ABO', 'ABOW', 'CNIW', 'O&T', 'EPH', 'TAX')
AND codeAdherent != 0
-- filter 2017 rows
AND dateFin >= '2017-01-01'
AND dateFin <  '2018-01-01'
-- filter rows where 2018 data does not exist
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM hs
    WHERE codeAdherent = t.codeAdherent
    AND dateFin >= '2018-01-01'
)
```

Comment: It seems that just one request can't do the job. I try another way : first, I select rows which date is  >= dateDebut ; then I collect data from them and discard those whose data is > dateFin. It's a little ugly but it works.

Comment: @Chamarejc see revised answer.

Comment: your request works well and it's more beautifull than mine. A question, I don't understand SELECT 1 under AND NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Chamarejc `EXISTS` is a SQL operator just like `IN`, `ALL`, `ANY` etc. You could learn about it on your own by searching for "SQL EXISTS operator".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
HAVING YEAR(MAX(hs.dateFin)) = 2017
```

Comment: No, it is not possible because if data exists on 2018 I will get an wrong answer

Comment: ...right. I changed it so that it should exclude rows with dateFin > 2017

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use aggregate functions like `Max()` inside `Where` clause. You can simply modify your `where` condition to include dates in year 2017 only, and then determine `Max()` date after group by.

```
SELECT MAX(hs.dateFin), hs.codeAdherent, hs.codeArticle 
FROM hs 
WHERE hs.codeFamilleArticle IN ('CNI', 'COT', 'ABO', 'ABOW',
                                'CNIW', 'O&T', 'EPH', 'TAX') 
AND hs.codeAdherent != 0 
WHERE hs.dateFin BETWEEN '2017-01-01' 
                     AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY hs.codeAdherent, hs.codeArticle
```

Comment: I try your suggestion and get that message :

1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'jcasaf.hs.dateFin' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: No errors this time but the answer includes data which contains 2017 and 2018. I would like to get data where 2018 doesn't exit.

Comment: @Chamarejc Without looking at sample data, it would be unclear now. please post relevant sample data and corresponding expected output. You may read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: Sure, it's not easy to understand what I want without sample. I can't do this now but I post it tomorrow

Comment: @Chamarejc ok once you post - please update me here so that I can take a look again. Also, you an set up https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ; or give `show create table` statement results. It would be faster to try with the data

Comment: I get this message :
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'jcasaf.hs.codeAdherent'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @Chamarejc i dont think so you should get this error. can you paste here, the complete query you are using ?

Comment: here under the complete query
SELECT MAX(hs.dateFin), hs.codeAdherent, hs.codeArticle 
FROM hs 
WHERE hs.codeFamilleArticle IN ('CNI', 'COT', 'ABO', 'ABOW',
                                'CNIW', 'O&T', 'EPH', 'TAX') 
AND hs.codeAdherent != 0 
WHERE hs.dateFin BETWEEN '2017-01-01' 
                     AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY hs.codeAdherent, hs.codeArticle